# Newbie question about Rosaria!

Tags: ros, rosaria, aria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use rosaria (instead of aria) to control my pioneer mobile robot! I found the link below about how to install and use rosaria, but I'm not quite understand

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA

I have some question!

- I downloaded .rosinstall file attached with the tutorial! But I don't know how to use it!
- How can I configure rosaria to program in an IDE like eclips
  e! I configured and used Aria in eclipse and I want to do it with rosaria!
- Is there any tutorial or open source code about using rosari
  a?

Thanks

Haquang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11724/newbie-question-about-rosaria!/) by [haquang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1292/haquang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe you are looking for [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs) tutorial on how to import a project into Eclipse. But you don't need to modify the driver. Just install it using the [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) tool and then rosmake it.
The "main" node is launched using

`rosnode ROSARIA RosAria`

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2